# How to display values in columns based on selected values of dropdown in smart table

Tags: angular, angular7, ng2-smart-table

I am using smart table and I have a dropdown in one column.based on the selected values in the drop down I want to display other columns in the same row.

```
variablesList = [
{ value: "1", title: 'A',description: "", response: 'Integer'},
{ value: "2", title: 'B' , description: "", response: 'Boolean'},
{ value: "3", title: 'C', description: "", response: 'Integer' }
];

columnInfo = {
actions: {
edit: true, add: true,
},
columns: {
name: {
title: 'Variables',
filter: false,
type: 'html',
editor: {
type: 'list',
config: {
list:
this.variablesList,
},
}
},
description: {
title: 'Description',
filter: false,
},
response: {
filter: false,
title: 'Response Type',
},
},
attr: {
class: "table table-responsive"
},
edit:{
editButtonContent: ''
},
delete: {
deleteButtonContent: ''
},
};
```

and this is my smart table.

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="columnInfo" [source]="variableSource">
                </ng2-smart-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible currently with smart table, I was working with smart-table a few weeks ago and it wasn't able to do what we need so we made a table from scratch to meet our requirements but to get it working with smart table functionally it's not hard at all, but if you need/have to use ng2-smart-table I would suggest putting an issue on their GitHub page https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table.